# Swagger with Spring-MVC and custom serializers

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, swagger

I am trying to use Swagger to document a Spring-MVC based REST-API and am having problems getting Swagger to reflect the use of custom serializers and deserializers.

Because the JSON must conform to an established format (which is not particularly well designed) and I wanted to have a properly designed API model in the Java classes, I have used a few custom implementations of JsonSerializer to generate the JSON output. When I enable Swagger with annotations in the Spring-MVC controllers, the generated documentation ignores the custom serializers and describes the model as if it had been serialized with the default Jackson settings. So far so good, I didn't really expect Swagger to automatically understand the implementation of the serializers.

What I however would expect (and I can't find anything about this in the Swagger documentation) is a way to use Swagger annotations on the relevant attributes in the model classes to manually describe the model. Am I missing something or is it really not possible to Swagger as a documentation tool in connection with custom serializers (or deserializers for that matter)?

Edit: The Swagger documentation is not particularly good, but I have already tried to work with @ApiModelProperty on the deviating properties. As far as I can see, it has absolutely no effect on the generated output (tested with Swagger-SpringMVC 0.8.5 and 0.9.5).

Answer (score 1):

You can use model substitutes for e.g. Lets say you have a service

```java
@RequestMapping(value = { "/some-resource" }, method = POST, 
    consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Void> 
    businessTypeEcho(@RequestBody CustomSerializableResource business) {
    return new CustomSerializableResource();
}
```

you can setup a type substitution rule that tells springmvc how to represent the custom serializable type in the swagger ui.

```java
@Bean //Don't forget the @Bean annotation
public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation(){
   return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .directModelSubstitute(CustomSerializableResource.class, SubstitutedSerializableResource.class)
        .includePatterns(".*pet.*");
}

class SubstitutedSerializableResource {
    //getters and setters that describe what 
    //CustomSerializableResource should look like in the UI
}
```

Unfortunately, this is going to create a parallel universe of types that aren't used at runtime.

**Update:**
If I understand your comment correctly, you're using it to format system-wide types i.e. booleans to Y/N or dates to mm/dd/yyyy perhaps. IMO, what you're probably looking for is to use model substitutes (see example above).

- Substitute `Date` with `String` (this is the [prescriptive guidance](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/overriding-models))  In the case of dates your only option to communicate the format expected unfortunately is only via a textual description of the particular field or property.
- Substitute `Boolean` with a enum you can create i.e. `YesNoEnum` that represents how you expect the objects to be serialized. This will provide the documentation with a set of allowed values.

At the end of the day, its a trade-off between creating these meta classes just for documentation vs. standardizing the API models to use serialization primitives as much as possible.

Comment: Creating and maintaining a complete copy of the data model just to document a few deviations from the default serialization rules does not seem to be a very good idea. It is also not obvious to me how mixins can solve the problem. According to the page you're linking to, they can be used to decouple the annotations from the model classes, but it is not clear to me how I with mixins (also without maintaining an almost identical second set of classes) can get Swagger to reflect the custom serializers in the generated documentation

Comment: There isn't a concrete example in your question. May be a concrete example of a type needing custom serialization would help. In addition to decoupling the annotations from the model class, mixins can also influence the shape of the json via annotations (to some extent). In any case, the library will __NOT__ be able to infer the effects of customer serializers.

Comment: What is not clear about the question, making a concrete example necessary to understand it? Having java.util.Date serialized with proprietary date formats or using the strings "yes" and "no" for boolean values would be two of the specific cases where I use custom serializers.

Comment: Your question is perfectly clear. Just trying to see if you had examples, so that I can suggest the best solution.

Comment: Substituting Date with String or boolean with a YesNoEnum unfortunately crashes with my requirement as stated in the question: "I wanted to have a properly designed API model in the Java classes". To make it unnecessarily complex, the established JSON format already uses e.g. both true/false (real boolean values), "true"/"false" (strings) and "yes"/"no" (strings) to represent boolean values. Using different data types in the Java model for boolean values just makes a mess there as well.

Comment: The entire model is some 20 classes with roundabout 200 properties (in total), of which only a handful are using custom serializers. Creating and maintainig a complete and almost identical copy of the entire model just to generate proper documentation does not seem to be a good idea. I was hoping that I could e.g. provide Swagger with a "manual" description of the few affected properties and not to rewrite the entire model.

Comment: ...and using the ```@ApiModelProperty``` doesn't help either? or do you not have control over the DTO's. Also my suggestion was to create type substitutes for only the models that have custom serializers... not the entire 20 classes or 200 properties!

Comment: If you mean to annotate the single properties with something like @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "java.lang.String"), this has absolutely no effect on the generated documentation. I had already attempted that, even if the documentation is quite fuzzy, but it does not change anything in the generated output.